# Is it possible to scrape data contained in a pseudo-element of a html with python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to develop a scraping code to retrieve tables from an italian Fantasy Football website. To do so, I wanted to parse the html of using python, BeautifulSoup and pandas.
However, when I parse the html code with BeautifulSoup, I cannot find any tables:

This code:

```
>>> # import libraries    
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> # define url of interest, request it and parse it
>>> url = 'https://www.fantacalcio.it/voti-fantacalcio-serie-a'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

>>> # find the first table in the code
>>> print(soup.find('table'))

None
```

I am new to html, but after some research I understood that the tables of interest might be contained in a pseudo-element, which is not appearing in the html code of the requested URL.
Is there a way to scrape the information contained in these tables?

[This is one of the tables highlighted in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTs0n.png)

[This is the related html snippet from the Chrome inspector tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj954.png), where the information is still available

This is how the same snippet looks after parsing:

```
>>> search = soup.find('div', id='Ata')
>>> print(search.prettify())

<div class="row no-gutter tbvoti" data-team="1" id="Ata">
</div>
```

empty...
Is it somehow possible to access the data?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What you see in the inspector is a pseudo element of the parent _followed by_ the table. I think you don't get the data because it is fetched like this: 1) Your browser requests the page and downloads it 2) Your browser downloads referenced resources like styles, scripts etc 3) Your Browser executes the scripts on the page 4) A script downloads the infos and renders the table to the page. When you access the page from your python script, you only get step 1. You will need to inspect deeper to see where the table data is comming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Network Tab you will find following url which retrieve table data.This link will give you first table info same way you can fetch all table info.

> https://www.fantacalcio.it/Servizi/Voti.ashx?s=2019-20&g=16&tv=314303547921&t=1

You can pandas library to read the table info and load into dataframe.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.fantacalcio.it/Servizi/Voti.ashx?s=2019-20&g=16&tv=314303547921&t=1'
df=pd.read_html(url)
print(df[0])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was doing the same as you did. But I was trying to find where they get that parameter of `t`. Any idea where that can be found?

Comment: @chitown88 : That's a good question.No mate not sure of that.

Comment: @chitown88 :  looks like the parameter t is hard coded value for each table.

Comment: ya that's what I figured. I was trying to see if that was returned as a list or json by post/get on the specific filters (trying to efficiently fetch the desired tables)

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing on the answer below (so accept KunduK's answer as it's correct), you can iterate through the tables and create a list of the dataframes. I couldn't find where they get that parameter for `t`, so I just have it going through them all.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for i in range(1,200):
    try:
        url = 'https://www.fantacalcio.it/Servizi/Voti.ashx?s=2019-20&g=16&tv=314303547921&t=%s' %i
        dfs.append(pd.read_html(url)[0])
    except:
        continue
```

**Output:**

```
print (dfs)
[             ATALANTA                    VOTO e FANTAVOTO      ...                BONUS/MALUS         
             ATALANTA                         Fantacalcio      ... Fonte unica Fantacalcio.it         
   Unnamed: 0_level_2 Unnamed: 1_level_2                V  Fv  ...                         Rp Rs Au As
0            PGOLLINI                NaN               65  45  ...                          -  -  -  -
1           DCASTAGNE                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
2           DDJIMSITI                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
3             DGOSENS                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
4           DHATEBOER                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
5           DPALOMINO                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
6              DTOLOI                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
7           CCOLLEY E                NaN                6   -  ...                          -  -  -  -
8            CDE ROON                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
9            CFREULER                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
10       CMALINOVSKYI                NaN               65  95  ...                          -  -  -  -
11           CPASALIC                NaN               55   5  ...                          -  -  -  -
12            ABARROW                NaN               65  75  ...                          -  -  -  1
13            AMURIEL                NaN                5   5  ...                          -  -  -  -
14       ALLGASPERINI                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -

[15 rows x 15 columns],               BOLOGNA                    VOTO e FANTAVOTO      ...                BONUS/MALUS         
              BOLOGNA                         Fantacalcio      ... Fonte unica Fantacalcio.it         
   Unnamed: 0_level_2 Unnamed: 1_level_2                V  Fv  ...                         Rp Rs Au As
0          PSKORUPSKI                NaN                6   5  ...                          -  -  -  -
1               DBANI                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
2         DDANILO LAR                NaN               55  45  ...                          -  -  -  -
3            DDENSWIL                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
4              DMBAYE                NaN                6   -  ...                          -  -  -  -
5           DTOMIYASU                NaN               65  75  ...                          -  -  -  1
6               CPOLI                  V                7  10  ...                          -  -  -  -
7           CSVANBERG                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
8              CMEDEL                NaN                6   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
9           CDZEMAILI                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
10          AORSOLINI                NaN               65   6  ...                          -  -  -  -
11           APALACIO                NaN               75  10  ...                          -  -  -  -
12         ASANSONE N                NaN                6  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
13         ASANTANDER                NaN               55  55  ...                          -  -  -  -
14      ALLMIHAJLOVIC                NaN               65  65  ...                          -  -  -  -

[15 rows x 15 columns],
....
```